# Gitlab-ci Child Pipeline Has The Same Name

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with GitLab ci mono-repo structure each downstream name has the same.
How can  I set customize names for Downstream Pipeline?

[image]

Comment: can you provide some more information like your gitlab-ci.yaml?

Comment: I asked to gitlab engineers and unfortunately they said "at the moment its not possible".

Answer (score 2):

Currently no way. There are several tickets in gitlab issues regarding this, looks like child pipeline name changing  will be available in nearest future.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/273382